# retrieving value from a label sends "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." exception

Tags: asp.net, webforms

*while there are other duplicate posts regarding this topic,they do not provide the answer in simple terms so a novice programmer like me don't understand.*

**Problem:**
*Not getting text values from a label inside the gridview so that i can update that value inside my database.*

**Source View:**

```
    <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="true"
AutoGenerateColumns="false"  PageSize="8" DataKeyNames="ID"
OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"
OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"
OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"
OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
<Columns>
<%--asset_name as 'Asset Name'--%>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Asset Name">
<ItemTemplate >
<asp:Label ID="labelAssetName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Asset Name") %>'>
</asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

---

**Code Behind:**

```
    Label lb2=(Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("labelAssetName");//Asset_Name
   int assettype = 0;
    if (lb2.Text == "Clothes & Apparels")
        assettype = 1;

    else if (lb2.Text == "Stationeries")
        assettype = 2;
    else if (lb2.Text == "Furnitures")
        assettype = 3;
    else if (lb2.Text == "Electronics")
        assettype = 4;
    else if (lb2.Text == "Transportations")
        assettype = 5;
    else if (lb2.Text == "Communications")
        assettype = 6;
```

*While i run the program, i get an exception as listed below:*

**System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

**Line 97:         if (lb2.Text == "Clothes & Apparels")**

I am getting values off the textboxes inside the same gridview, but i cannot get label value.

*I'd be grateful for any help explaining the cause of this exception and method to solve it in simple terms.*

Comment: Which event is this in the code behind.?

Comment: @khalidkhan this is the rowupdating event for gridview

Answer (score 0):

Please try and add an EditItemTemplate for the gridview and then add labelAssetName label to that Template and then try getting it in the RowUpdating event. I think currently you only have itemtemplate. If this does not solve your problem then please let me know.

Also please look into this snippet, If you can. It might help.

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/GridView-RowUpdating-event-example-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

if you still have the problem. Please let me know.

I hope it helps.